# Bug in a PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to print "1" if there are at least two of the same figure in the match, else 0.

**What is wrong in the regex?**

```
if ( max ( array_map ('strlen', preg_split('/([0-9])[^0-9]*\1/', "1 2 3 1 4") ) ) == 1 )
        echo 1;
else
        echo 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo preg_match('/(?<=^|[^0-9])([0-9)+)(?=[^0-9]).*(?<=[^0-9])\1(?=[^0-9]|$)/', "1 2 3 1 4");
```

Will match for any repeated number in the sequence, and echo 1 if there is something repeated, 0 if not.

(Original version just looked for something repeated after each other, this matches repeated anywhere in the string)

Comment: Your command gives me "0" although it should give "1". I am not sure where the bug is in your command.

Comment: If the input is always as shown (i.e. space seperated), it's much simpler to use `\b` instead of all that lookbehind/lookahead noise. (The only time `\b` would fail is if alphas or underscore are used as delimiters.)

Comment: This can then give a simpler expression of `\b([0-9]++).*?\b\1\b`

Comment: hey, sorry, seems PHP doesnt class the start of a line as not being a number :D

I've amended my answer

Comment: @Mez: Your regez still has the same bug. I modified your answer sligthly in trying to understand it. --- @Peter: Your regex should apparently have only one +. Your regex to Mez's example gives 0 which is surprising. - I am not completely sure about the definition of ´\b´.

Comment: Aha, Masi, that's cause of the \1 - If you change the double quotes to single quotes, it works (about to do this)

Comment: This input "65|19|24|56|85|11|13|14|53|6|60" should return zero. Your regex returns 1. What should be changed in the regex to get the feature?

Comment: Are the items always space seperated?

Comment: Mez: They are not always separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The [^0-9]* matches any number of NON-digit characters. So if there's another number, it will fail the match. Try replacing [^0-9]* with a simple .*, which will match digits or non-digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It should print 1 when there is a repeat number.

```
if(0 == strlen(preg_replace('/.*([0-9]).+\1.*/', '', '1 2 3 1 5 4')))
     echo 1;
else echo 0;
```

The regex `/.*([0-9]).+\1.*/` will match a number and another number (with `.+` or anything in between them).

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't take into account 2 digit numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try a lookahead assertion.  I use "The Regex Coach" whenever I'm trying to figure something out.  It doesn't give you hints or anything, but it does give immediate feedback.

Test string: "1 2 3 1 4 3"
Regex: ([0-9])(?=.*\1)

Basically the ()'s around the [0-9] store the result, and the lookahead (?= matches .* - any character and then \1 - what was matched first (so it looks for any number and then looks ahead to see if that number occurs again)

This will match both "1" and "3"

I'm not quite sure if php supports lookaheads, but that's my take.

Comment: it will also match

1 2 3 4 13